# R merge two dat frames based on column and list

Tags: r, merge

Is there anyway I can merge two data frames in R based on column which is in list form to get sum of other column. Some sample data below:

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c("1", "2"), 
                      band = list(c("c1", "c2", "c3"), "c4"), 
                      samples = list(c(32, 2, 61), 20), 
                      time = list(c(307, 2, 238), 74)), 
                 .Names = c("id", "band", "samples", "time"), 
                 row.names = 0:1, class = "data.frame")
```

[image]

```
df2 <- structure(list(id = c("1", "3"), 
                      band = list(c("c1", "c4"), "c1"), 
                      samples = list(c(1, 2), 2), 
                      time = list(c(4, 2), 7)), 
                 .Names = c("id", "band", "samples", "time"), 
                 row.names = 0:1, class = "data.frame")
```

[image]

I'd like to get a merge data from df1 and df2 based on id and bands column. Unfortunately, the bands column is in list form and I need to sum the samples and time column based on elements from the bands column, which is in list from. I'm expecting the below

[image: enter code here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use `unnest` of the `tidyr`-package and `bind_rows` in combination with a `group_by` and `summarize` from `dplyr`.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
```

`unnest` takes care of the list column:

```
df1_unnest <- df1 %>% 
  unnest()

df1_unnest
#   id band samples time
# 1  1   c1      32  307
# 2  1   c2       2    2
# 3  1   c3      61  238
# 4  2   c4      20   74

df2_unnest <- df2 %>% 
  unnest()
```

`bind_rows` combines the two new data.frames:

```
new_df <- bind_rows(df1_unnest, df2_unnest)

new_df
#   id band samples time
# 1  1   c1      32  307
# 2  1   c2       2    2
# 3  1   c3      61  238
# 4  2   c4      20   74
# 5  1   c1       1    4
# 6  1   c4       2    2
# 7  3   c1       2    7
```

Then with `group_by` and `summarize_all` you can sum the values for id 1, band c1:

```
new_df <- new_df %>% 
  group_by(id, band) %>% 
  summarize_all(sum)

new_df
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   id [?]
#   id    band  samples  time
#   <chr> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 1     c1         33   311
# 2 1     c2          2     2
# 3 1     c3         61   238
# 4 1     c4          2     2
# 5 2     c4         20    74
# 6 3     c1          2     7
```

If you need the list columns you can do

```
new_df_list <- new_df %>%
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarize_all(list)

print.data.frame(new_df_list)
#   id           band      samples           time
# 1  1 c1, c2, c3, c4 33, 2, 61, 2 311, 2, 238, 2
# 2  2             c4           20             74
# 3  3             c1            2              7
```

Comment: @Kath.Thanks for solution. Just wondering would this be fast work on large data set like 2 or 5 millions rows

Comment: Hmm `unnest` takes a while for large datasets, but `bind_rows` should be quite fast as well as the `group_by` and `summarize_all`. I'd try it on a subset of your data. Maybe you can do smart subsetting such that you don't have to unnest the complete data.frame. Next time you should specify in your question that you are looking for a solution for a large dataset.

Comment: Just one more thing, Is there any limit on number of rows in R?

Comment: I don't know - maybe you should ask a new question and be a more specific. I think there is not a limit on the number of rows but rather on the workspace capacity.

Comment: Yes.. I think it did